# CMake - Build executable and dependencies in flat hierarchy

Tags: c++, macos, cmake

I am learning CMake and have been trying to understand how one would go about linking static libraries that are separate projects to an executable, then configure the root project to correctly collect dependencies for all executable targets and build all executables.

My hierarchy is like this:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── build
│   ├── include
│   └── src
│       └── main.cpp
├── square
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── build
│   ├── include
│   │   └── lolerji_square.h
│   └── src
│       └── lolerji_square.cpp
└── CMakeLists.txt
```

Now, my goal is to have several different apps in this hierarchy similar as to `app` and many static libs such as `square`. Each app may reference any static libs in this hierarchy. However, I have no clue how I might configure `CMakeLists.txt` files.

The goal is, to allow each dependency to be separately maintained, while when building the executables, each dependency is compiled from the source if necessary. I want to achieve this with the most modern approach as possible. Specifically, I want to avoid using `add_subdirectory()` and `include_directories()` if possible, as from what I understood they might introduce shenanigans I'd rather avoid.

I am fairly new at CMake, and my approach to this might be wrong. Even so, I would be happy to know if this is achievable, if so how, and if it is not the recommended approach to this kind of problem, what would be the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the structure to build.

First, I configured each library so they all have `src` and `include` directories. The header files are necessary for building, as well as providing interface.

Library CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(<folder name>)

add_library(<folder name>lib STATIC)
target_sources(<folder name>lib PRIVATE src/source1.cpp src/source2.cpp ...)
target_include_directories(<folder name>lib PUBLIC include)
```

Then, for executable projects:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(<folder name>)

add_executable(<folder name>)
target_sources(<folder name> PRIVATE src/main.cpp src/othersource.cpp ...)
target_link_libraries(<folder name> PRIVATE lib1 lib2 ...)
```

In the root CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(<folder name>)

add_subdirectory(lib1)
add_subdirectory(lib2)
# add other libs here...

add_subdirectory(app1)
add_subdirectory(app2)
# add other executables here...
```

Then, using `cmake -S . -B build` in the root directory, I can build all libraries and executables as separate projects and have everything under ./build

However, this approach compiles all source each time, so if the libraries take long to compile, this approach would not be ideal I think.

---

### UPDATE:

I updated the configuration. This builds and is using export/import for projects

In library project CMakeLists.txt files:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(<library folder name>)

add_library(<library name> STATIC)
target_sources(<library name> PRIVATE src/source1.cpp src/source2.cpp ...)
target_include_directories(<library name> PUBLIC include)

# Add libraries if necessary here...
target_link_libraries(<library name> PRIVATE lib1 lib2 ...)

export(TARGETS <library name> FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BUILD_DIR}/<library name>Targets.cmake)
```

In executable CMakeLists.txt files:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(<folder name>)

add_executable(<executable name>)
target_sources(<executable name> PRIVATE src/source1.cpp src/source2.cpp ...)
target_include_directories(<executable name> PUBLIC include)

# Add link libraries
target_link_libraries(<executable name> PRIVATE lib1 lib2 ...)
```

Finally, in the root CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(<project name>)

# Add library project subdirectories
add_subdirectory(lib1)
add_subdirectory(lib2)
...

# Add executable project subdirectories
add_subdirectory(app1)
add_subdirectory(app2)
...
```